# Whenever I clicked on the play button it's starts a same song (previous song is also playing ) , it goes in infinite times

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

This method play the song number of times I clicked on the play button. it should not happen but its not working accordingly

```
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override


        public void onClick(View v) {
            path = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.chelseafc);
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, path);


            length = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

            if (length == 0) {
                mediaPlayer.start();

                // length = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

            } else if (length != 0) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(length);
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
            // mediaPlayer.start();


        }
    });
```

Comment: Why not using `MediaPlayer.isPlaying()` method before starting new song

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not seem to stop previous songs.

Assuming that this is the only place where `mediaPlayer` is initialized, you could replace this line: `mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, path);` with the following:

```
if((mediaPlayer != null) && (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()))
    mediaPlayer.stop();

mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, path);
```

You probably also need to close the current media player first before starting a new one.